# I have a table images and album_images. Is the album_images table unnecessary?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I've created a website where a user can upload a single image or a whole album of images and 3 views - one for displaying all single `images`, one for displaying all `albums` (just the title image of each album) and one for displaying all `album_images` that have `album_id` of the album.

My tables are as follows:

```
Table: images
Columns: id, name, description, user_id, file_name, upvotes, downvotes, views

Table: albums
Columns: id, name, description, user_id, thumbnail, upvotes, downvotes, views

Table: album_images
Columns: id, album_id, file_name
```

A couple of reasons why I created a second table that would contain images:

1 - I wanted to have my home page display all single images without displaying any of the album images. My reasoning was that an image from an album might not make any sense if seen without the rest of the images. I know believe that this problem could be bypassed by creating an `is_album_image` column that would be false if it is a single image and true if it is an album image. This way I could still only show single images on my home page whilst removing the second images table.

2 - The `album_images` table doesn't have many of the images columns like `name` and `description` because the album images don't need those, the album itself will have that information, the only information I need about the album images is the `id` of the album they are in and their `file_name`. I believe that this means I'd have to add more columns to the `images` table and have some of the old columns be nullable if I wanna merge the two tables.

I would really love to hear opinions on whether my `album_images` table is unnecessary and if I should try to merge them. Of course I'd have to change some stuff in my controllers but I don't mind as long as it looks and works better.

Comment: I think you don't need to add the table, what you have to do is just add one column `album_id` in the images table and if the image is single the added column will have the value null so you will not need `is_album_image` :)

Comment: Why not just have an `album_id` column in the `images` table? This seems to be a many-to-one relationship, not many-to-many

Comment: But wouldn't I have to make name, description, upvotes, downvotes and views nullable since album images won't have those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, just need a One to Many Relationship

```
Table: images
Columns: id, name, description, user_id, album_id, file_name, upvotes, downvotes, views

Table: albums
Columns: id, name, description, user_id, thumbnail, upvotes, downvotes, views
```

You can define your relations for Eloquent in your album, image and user model.

Comment: But I would have to make name, description, upvotes, downvotes and views nullable because I don't use those when uploading album images, however, at least name and description are mandatory when uploading single images. Therefore if I try to upload an album image when name is not nullable, I'll get an error

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you that is necessary, unless you're trying to save the path of the image, for example.